# Having a NSTimer running background

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer, background-process

I've seen hundreds of solutions of how to get a NSTimer to run in the background.

I know that it is possible, just look at apps like Strava and Runkepper that tracks your time when working out.

But what is the best practice solution for doing so? I can't find one unison solution for this.

Also, I would like the NSTimer to be used across different UIViewControllers. How is this done as a best practice?

Thanks in regards! :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you would like to achieve? I don't really understand your problem

Comment: Hundreds of solutions???? I bet you can't named one, `NSTimer` does not run in the background! :)

Comment: The reason why e.g. Runkeeper can use your app in the background is because it uses Core Location and receives GPS updates subsequent to which they can execute code :)

Comment: @SebastianWramba I was maby a bit unclear. I want to have a timer running while the app is not in the foreground. Just like Apples own timer app.

Comment: @nburk Okay, so NSTimer might not run in the background, but I need A timer in the background. And hundreds? Yes, search for "NSTimer in background" and see all the different ways people has solved this. I'm looking for the best practice solution. Strava and Runkeeper also has a timer? How can they run in the background? Using timestamps when leaving foreground?

Comment: I added an answer, it sounds like you want to use `UILocalNotification` rather than `NSTimer` if you want to have something similar like Apple's own timer app.

Answer (score 2):

NSTimers don't run in the background. Store the current time and the elapsed time of the timer when you got the background. When you come back to the foreground, you set up a new timer, using those two pieces of information to setup any state or data that needs to reflect the total elapsed time.
To share between viewCOntroller, just have one object implement this timer, and expose a property on it (e.g. elapsedTime) that gets updated every time interval . Then you can have the viewCOntrollers (that have a reference to that object) observe that property for changes.

Comment: This sounds like the solution I need! I will try that out :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You Can Try This Code  in Your application NSTimers don't run in the background. acceding to apple But We Try forcefully Only 3 mint
AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *myTimer;
- (BOOL) isMultitaskingSupported;
- (void) timerMethod:(NSTimer *)paramSender;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

        if ([self isMultitaskingSupported] == NO)
        {
            return;
        }
        self.myTimer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerMethod:) userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
        self.backgroundTaskIdentifier =[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
            [self endBackgroundTask];
        }];
    }
```

## pragma mark - NSTimer Process

```
- (BOOL) isMultitaskingSupported
{
    BOOL result = NO;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]
         respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]){ result = [[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported];
    }
    return result;
}


- (void) timerMethod:(NSTimer *)paramSender{

    NSTimeInterval backgroundTimeRemaining =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining];
    if (backgroundTimeRemaining == DBL_MAX)
    {
        NSLog(@"Background Time Remaining = Undetermined");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Background Time Remaining = %.02f Seconds",backgroundTimeRemaining);
    }
}
- (void) endBackgroundTask
{
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue(); __weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^(void) { AppDelegate *strongSelf = weakSelf; if (strongSelf != nil){
        [strongSelf.myTimer invalidate];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
         endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTaskIdentifier];
        strongSelf.backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    } });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, `NSTimer` won't work in the background, backround execution on iOS is quite tricky and only works in certain cases, check the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) on the topic, also [this is an excellent read](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html) to acquire more background knowledge.

As for your case, it sound like you want to use `UILocalNotification`. As I understand from your comment:
`I want to have a timer running while the app is not in the foreground. Just like Apples own timer app.`

Apple's timer app uses `UILocalNotification`. It gives you a way to schedule a notification which will appear at a certain point in time to the user, regardless of whether the app is in the foreground or background! All you have to do in your app is schedule a notification, e.g. like this:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = dateTime;
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alert Fired at %@", dateTime];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Then iOS will handle the rest for you :)

Comment: My timer will not stop in the future, because I need an "infinite" timer. (I want to have a counter running so I can have a live calculating app of the costs of having the meeting. 3 persons with 100 dollars per hour salary equals 300 dollars for one hours, but I want it to count upwards).

Comment: What meeting? I think you have to me more clear on what you want to achieve, otherwise it will be difficult to help you find a solution...

Comment: Sorry, A meeting, not "the" meeting. I want an infinite count up whenever I hold a meeting, to show my colleagues how much the meeting costs. (A cool gimmick to keep meetings short).

Comment: What do you want to count up? Can you lay out your use case more clearly?

Comment: Like the Worldometer: http://www.worldometers.info/ Counting up with set values, running "infinitely".

Comment: then why does the timer have to run in the background?

Comment: I need to press start when I want to start calculating. And earlier today I thought I needed a timer, but as @Joride explained, remembering the timestamp when you started and keep that while the app is in the background, and read the value when opening the app again does the trick.

Comment: yeah... you can always use `NSDate` to calculate back the time I guess... so your issue is solved?